# How can I subtract the last two rows of this table by 2?

Tags: r, sorting, plot, subtraction

```
     Loc Var  Y1    Y2
1.   UF   M  81.0  80.7
2.   UF   S 105.4  82.3
3.   UF   V 119.7  80.4
```

I need a quick way, without rebuilding the table from scratch.

Thanks in advance!

R program

It has around 30 rows i just omitted them for time's shake.

I want the two last columns (Y1,Y2) subtracted for all the rows(1,2,3,...30)

Comment: Something like `df1[(nrow(df1)-1):nrow(df1), 3:4] <- df1[(nrow(df1)-1):nrow(df1), 3:4]-2`

Comment: it doesn't recognize the df1 object

Comment: I assume that you have the object name as 'df1'.  If it different change it to that

Comment: i have not named the object at all. i just want to subtract the columns y1,yw by 2 do i really need to name a new object?

Comment: Have u read the data into R?

Comment: of course i have

Comment: Okay, can u show the code,  I assume that `df1 <- read.csv('yourdata.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: > nr <- nrow(df)
> nc <- ncol(df)
> df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] <- df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] - 2
Error in (nr - 1):nr : argument of length 0

Comment: Okay, it works for me based on the example showed.  You may check the structure of your dataset. i.e. `str(df)`.  Also your edit `I want the two last columns (Y1,Y2) subtracted for all the rows(1,2,3,...30)` and title `How can I subtract the last two rows of this table by 2?` is mismatching.  I am done with this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but if you just want to subtract two from the `Y1` and `Y2` columns for rows 2 and 3, then you can use this:

```
df[2:3, c("Y1", "Y2")] <- df[2:3, c("Y1", "Y2")] - 2
```

More generally:

```
nr <- nrow(df)
nc <- ncol(df)
df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] <- df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] - 2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Loc = c("UF", "UF", "UF"),   # I'm calling your data frame 'df'
                 Var = c("M", "S", "V"),
                 Y1 = c(81.0, 105.4, 119.7),
                 Y2 = c(80.7, 82.3, 80.4))
```

## Demo

Comment: hey i want to subtract two points for the column Y1,Y2. It has also around 30 other which i didnt posted, so i need something more general.

Comment: @J.Abrahms My answer targets only columns `Y1` and `Y2`.  If this isn't what you want, then update your question.  Also, the second part of my answer will target the last two rows, regardless of how many rows you  have in your data frame.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I want to subtract  the last two columns (Y1,Y2) by 2. So for example 81-> 79. But in total there are 30 rows so 30 Y1s and Y2s. I just omitted the rest rows for time's shake.

Comment: @J.Abrahms Answer updated assuming you want to subtract 2 from the bottom 2x2 portion of your data frame.

Comment: Error in (nr - 1):nr : argument of length 0 this is what shows me

Comment: Did you also include the code `nr <- nrow(df)` and `nc <- ncol(df)` ?  Open the demo link in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: > nr <- nrow(df)
    > nc <- ncol(df)
    > df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] <- df[(nr-1):nr, (nc-1):nc] - 2  
      Error in (nr - 1):nr : argument of length 0

Comment: It runs in the demo with the most general terms.  I don't know what is happening with you, but my guess is that your data has a problem.

Comment: http://rextester.com/CSN51397 here is the full list i want all the numbers on the columns Y1 and Y2 to be subtracted by 2.

Comment: OK, @akrun is giving up on this and I am getting there too.  Your demo link just shows a bunch of data, no actual code.  Show me a demo where my code fails, or give up on my answer.

Comment: @J.Abrahms You are pasting in the console prompt {">"} and your GUI (or not)  is not capable of removing those. Use Tim's code exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Given Tim's Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Loc = c("UF", "UF", "UF"),   # I'm calling your data frame 'df'
             Var = c("M", "S", "V"),
             Y1 = c(81.0, 105.4, 119.7),
             Y2 = c(80.7, 82.3, 80.4))
```

You can get the desired result by using dplyr functions:

```
library(dplyr) # Load the library

df2<- df %>%
       mutate(Y1=Y1-2, Y2=Y2-2)
```

You will get this:

```
df2
Loc Var    Y1   Y2
1  UF   M  79.0 78.7
2  UF   S 103.4 80.3
3  UF   V 117.7 78.4
```

This will work just fine for any number of rows you have for Y1 and Y2